# How to tackle this JavaScript mini assignment from freeCodeCamp?

Tags: javascript

Basically the title,

I just started learning JavaScript (through freeCodeCamp) and it's taking me **a lot** of effort to understand even the most basic of things. The explanation of '*the concepts*' is clear and concise, and the examples are also very good. However, I struggle with implementing it when taking on the little assignments. For example, [this assignment](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/record-collection).

I appreciate anyone who comments and is willing to teach me/explain to me the basics of tackling these problems. Learning day by day, thank you so much!

(Also, with said difficulties, I experience a lot of 'down' moments where I feel like giving up because I find it so difficult. Thinking I'll never be able to accomplish anything in the field of programming. Any tips to overcome that?)

```js
// Setup
const recordCollection = {
  2548: {
    albumTitle: 'Slippery When Wet',
    artist: 'Bon Jovi',
    tracks: ['Let It Rock', 'You Give Love a Bad Name']
  },
  2468: {
    albumTitle: '1999',
    artist: 'Prince',
    tracks: ['1999', 'Little Red Corvette']
  },
  1245: {
    artist: 'Robert Palmer',
    tracks: []
  },
  5439: {
    albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold'
  }
};

// Only change code below this line
function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
  return records;
}

updateRecords(recordCollection, 5439, 'artist', 'ABBA');
```

Comment: Please post the assignment as text here, not as a link to an image.

Comment: Your second question might be more appropriate in [cseducators.se].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Don't let the initial learning curve defeat you. Learning the fundamentals, learning how to think about programming problems, is one of the hardest parts. It won't always be this hard. The concepts and patterns you're learning now will carry you far once you've internalized them.

Comment: The best advice for overcoming your 'down' moments is to focus on the successes you have so far. Finding small/simple projects you can build that are useful to you to accomplish meaningful tasks can also be super motivating. Try to tie the JavaScript programs to other projects or interests you know a lot or are passionate about. When I first learned coding, I was building text-based story games and simple applications that did useful things like give a standard header on all my website pages. You don't have to know everything to make something useful or fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this assignment, you are learning how to work with objects. Your task is to write an `updateRecords` function that takes 4 [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) `records`, `id`, `prop`, and `value`, then updates and returns a new `records` object with some changes, as specified in the assignment.

Inside our function, we need to update or delete a specific property of the `records` object, based on the arguments passed to the function.

They've provided you with an `updateRecords` function that returns `records` without any changes:

```
function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
  return records;
}
```

They give you a list of rules to modify the `records` object passed to the function.

Two of these rules apply if `prop` is "tracks". Let's start with the other three general rules first, then we'll move on to handle those "tracks" cases.

The 3 general rules are:

- Your function must always return the entire record collection object.

  - *We accomplish this with `return records;`, which they gave us.*
- If prop isn't tracks and value isn't an empty string, update or set that album's prop to value.
- If value is an empty string, delete the given prop property from the album.

## If value is an empty string, delete the given prop property from the album.

So if the value is an empty string, we need to delete the property, otherwise, we need to change the property. Let's start there with a simple [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...els) statement, and [delete the property from the object](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/delete-properties-from-a-javascript-object) if the `value` argument passed to our function is empty.

```
function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
    if (value) {
        // If prop isn't tracks and value isn't an empty string, update or set that album's prop to value.
    } else {
        // If value is an empty string, delete the given prop property from the album
        delete records[id][prop];
    }
    return records;
}
```

## If prop isn't tracks and value isn't an empty string, update or set that album's prop to value.

```
function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
    if (value) {
        if (prop === 'tracks') {
            // if property is "tracks" we'll handle that here next.
        } else {
            // if property isn't tracks update or set that album's prop to value
            records[id][prop] = value;
        }
    } else {
        delete records[id][prop];
    }
    return records;
}
```

We've added a simple nested `if...then` statement to check if the `prop` argument passed to our function is "tracks", if it is, we'll write some code to handle that scenario soon. Otherwise, we use `records[id)][prop] = value;` to update the value of that property.

Now let's handle the cases where `prop` is "tracks".

- If prop is tracks but the album doesn't have a tracks property, create an empty array and add value to it.
- If prop is tracks and value isn't an empty string, add value to the end of the album's existing tracks array.

Take a look at the given `recordCollection` Object (copied below).

```
const recordCollection = {
  2548: {
    albumTitle: 'Slippery When Wet',
    artist: 'Bon Jovi',
    tracks: ['Let It Rock', 'You Give Love a Bad Name']
  },
  2468: {
    albumTitle: '1999',
    artist: 'Prince',
    tracks: ['1999', 'Little Red Corvette']
  },
  1245: {
    artist: 'Robert Palmer',
    tracks: []
  },
  5439: {
    albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold'
  }
};
```

The first three entries have a `track` property that is an Array.

You'll notice that the last entry doesn't have a `track` property, for example:  `tracks: 'Let It Rock', 'You Give Love a Bad Name']`. In these cases, we want to push the `value` to the end of the Array.

We can accomplish this with `records[id][prop].push(value);`

However, You'll also see that the last entry is missing a `track` property. Since no `track` property exists there is no Array to push the `value` to. Therefore, we need to set that property equal to an array containing our value.

We can accomplish this with `records[id][prop] = [value];`

So let's add an `if...else` statement to check if the `records` with our `id` contains a `tracks` property. If so, we push our `value` to the existing array. If not, we set the `tracks` property on that entry to an array containing our `value`.

```
function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
    if (value) {
        if (prop === 'tracks') {
            // Check to see if this record has a 'tracks' property
            if (records[id][prop]) {
                // If the album does have a tracks property, add value to the end of the album's existing tracks array.
                records[id][prop].push(value);
            } else {
                // If the album doesn't have a tracks property, create an empty array and add value to it.
                records[id][prop] = [value];
            }
        } else {
            records[id][prop] = value;
        }
    } else {
        delete records[id][prop];
    }
    return records;
}
```

​

Your full answer will look something like this:

```js
// Setup
const recordCollection = {
    2548: {
        albumTitle: 'Slippery When Wet',
        artist: 'Bon Jovi',
        tracks: ['Let It Rock', 'You Give Love a Bad Name']
    },
    2468: {
        albumTitle: '1999',
        artist: 'Prince',
        tracks: ['1999', 'Little Red Corvette']
    },
    1245: {
        artist: 'Robert Palmer',
        tracks: []
    },
    5439: {
        albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold'
    }
};

function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
    if (value) {
        if (prop === 'tracks') {
            if (records[id][prop]) {
                records[id][prop].push(value);
            } else {
                records[id][prop] = [value];
            }
        } else {
            records[id][prop] = value;
        }
    } else {
        delete records[id][prop];
    }
    
    console.log(records);
    return records;
}

updateRecords(recordCollection, 2548, "artist", "")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your elaborate reply, I'm sure it'll help me a lot! I've actually decided to take a different approach. Going to read Eloquent JavaScript, then start anew. When the time comes, I'll come back to your comment regarding this assignment! Thanks.